# Getting exact domain name from any URL

Tags: c#, dns, uri, tld

I need to extract the exact domain name from any Url.

For example,

Url : http://www.google.com --> Domain : google.com

Url : http://www.google.co.uk/path1/path2 --> Domain : google.co.uk

How can this is possible in c# ? Is there a complete TLD list or a parser for that task ?

Answer (score 31):

You can use the [Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) to access all components of an URI:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.google.co.uk/path1/path2");

var host = uri.Host;

// host == "www.google.co.uk"
```

---

However, there is no built-in way to strip the sub-domain "www" off "www.google.co.uk". You need to implement your own logic, e.g.

```
var parts = host.ToLowerInvariant().Split('.');

if (parts.Length >= 3 &&
    parts[parts.Length - 1] == "uk" &&
    parts[parts.Length - 2] == "co")
{
    var result = parts[parts.Length - 3] + ".co.uk";

    // result == "google.co.uk"
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Use:

```
new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5984361/c-sharp-getting-exact-domain-name-from-any-url?s=45faab89-43eb-41dc-aa5b-8a93f2eaeb74#new-answer").GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).Replace("/www.", "/").Replace("http://", ""));
```

Input:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5984361/c-sharp-getting-exact-domain-name-from-any-url?s=45faab89-43eb-41dc-aa5b-8a93f2eaeb74#new-answer
```

Output:

```
stackoverflow.com
```

Also works for the following.

http://www.google.com → google.com

http://www.google.co.uk/path1/path2 → google.co.uk

http://localhost.intranet:88/path1/path2 → localhost.intranet:88

http://www2.google.com → www2.google.com

Comment: It will not work, `new Uri("http://www.google.com").GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).Replace("http://", "") ≡ "www.google.com"`

Comment: See updated. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: For a different scheme, you can use like this: Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            string domain = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).Replace("/www.", "/").Replace(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Scheme), "");

Answer (score 7):

Try the System.Uri class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

```
new Uri("http://www.google.co.uk/path1/path2").Host
```

which returns "www.google.co.uk". From there it's string manipulation. :/

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
var uri =new Uri(Request.RawUrl); // to get the url from request or replace by your own
var domain = uri.GetLeftPart( UriPartial.Authority );
```

Input:

```
Url = http://google.com/?search=true&q=how+to+use+google
```

Result:

```
domain = google.com
```

Comment: does not work, RawUrl does not return .com address

Comment: @Nick: see the next line too

Comment: I used your entire code. This solution may have worked in the past but did not work for .net 4.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant, without dependencies:

```
string GetDomainPart(string url)
{
    var doubleSlashesIndex = url.IndexOf("://");
    var start = doubleSlashesIndex != -1 ? doubleSlashesIndex + "://".Length : 0;
    var end = url.IndexOf("/", start);
    if (end == -1)
        end = url.Length;

    string trimmed = url.Substring(start, end - start);
    if (trimmed.StartsWith("www."))
        trimmed = trimmed.Substring("www.".Length );
    return trimmed;
}
```

Examples:

`http://www.google.com → google.com`

`http://www.google.co.uk/path1/path2 → google.co.uk`

`http://localhost.intranet:88/path1/path2 → localhost.intranet:88`

`http://www2.google.com → www2.google.com`